# Write an Ip Address with EPPlus

Tags: ip, epplus

I'm trying to write some IP Adress into an excel using EPPlus.
In fact what it is not really an ip adress -> 300.278.100 it represent a subnet. I try this format:

```
cell.Style.Numberformat.Format = "##0.##0.##0";
cell.Value = val;
```

and

```
cell.Style.Numberformat.Format = "@";
cell.Value = val;
```

[image]

And always get something similar to above picture.
And as you see i get different results. Where we can see 36892 it should be "1.1.1".
Some results apear like numbers stored like text, and other are text.
I would like everyone of them are stored like text without warning or like number with ip like format.

Does anyone know how can I implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is there is more then one decimal point which wouldnt make much sense in a number.  About the closest I can think of if you want to keep everything as numbers would be something like:

```
//With Leading zeros - prints as "001.001.001" in excel
//Should work for all subnets
sheet1.Cells[1, 2].Style.Numberformat.Format = "000\\.000\\.000";
sheet1.Cells[1, 2].Value = 1001001;
```

Not sure there is a way to optionally show in-between zeros inside a real number like that.  I suppose you could adjust for each cell like:

```
//Without Leading zeros but has to be adjusted for each value
//print as "1.1.1" in excel
sheet1.Cells[1, 3].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0\\.0\\.0";
sheet1.Cells[1, 3].Value = 111;

//print as "1.11.1" in excel
sheet1.Cells[1, 4].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0\\.00\\.0";
sheet1.Cells[1, 4].Value = 1111;
```

Not exactly pretty.  Otherwise, could just leave out the formatting and set them as strings.